# Renaming a file in Git

Tags: git

I have a file in Git called `100_Test_Customer_Team_abc.txt` which has been pushed to the remote repository. I made a mistake in the name - the team is supposed to be in capital letters, so I want to rename it to `100_Test_Customer_Team_ABC.txt`.

I have used:

```
git mv 100_Test_Customer_Team_abc.txt 100_Test_Customer_Team_ABC.txt
```

But I get the following error:

> fatal: destination exists

How can I rename it?

Comment: Is the FileSystem Case-Sensitive?

Comment: Reset the head and add the file again

Comment: Windows operating system

Comment: `git mv 100_Test_Customer_Team_abc.txt tmp && git mv tmp 100_Test_Customer_Team_ABC.txt`, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this solution:

```
 git mv --force 100_Test_Customer_Team_abc.txt 100_Test_Customer_Team_ABC.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Move it using the **mv** command:

```
mv 100_Test_Customer_Team_abc.txt 100_Test_Customer_Team_ABC.txt
```

Since you are using Windows, just you can simply rename the file via [Windows Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer).

Then add all changes as tracked changes: `git add -A`. You will see then that Git tracks the deleted/added as a renamed in `git status`

Now you can simply `git commit -m 'Renamed file'` and push to remote.